Have roughly half of incumbents who sought the presidency again failed?
I recently came across this Twitter thread from famed data analyst (and much maligned political analyst) Nate Silver:

The historical claim in the first tweet was kind of surprising to me (so yeah, not "well understood" I guess). Is it accurate? About how likely were presidential incumbents who sought another term to receive one?
To address some niche cases, I'd think someone who got elected but couldn't serve out their entire term for some reason would still count. As for Incumbents who failed to get their party's nomination, I'd think recent cases of incumbents dropping out during the middle of primary season, like Johnson and Biden should not count (but I'd accept answers that feel otherwise, if the disputed incidents are noted). Incumbents who failed to get their party's nomination for another term as candidates on the convention floor (as occasionally happened before the modern primary system) I'll leave that to answerer judgement.

Doing a quick count, there are 19 Presidents who were successfully re-elected as incumbents (15 who were elected twice or more, Truman who served out the rest of FDR's last term before winning in his own right, Roosevelt ditto for McKinley, Coolidge ditto for Harding, and Johnson ditto for JFK) or 20 if you count Cleveland's non-consecutive terms.
Of incumbents who ran and lost in the year given in brackets, we get:

John Adams (1800)
John Quincy Adams (1828)
van Buren (1840) notable for being the first incumbent not to be reelected who was not named John Adams
Cleveland (1888)
Harrison (1892) - notable for being defeated by Cleveland, whom he defeated the previous election
Taft and Roosevelt (1912) - Teddy Roosevelt was the president before Taft, running as a 3rd party against him; both lost to Wilson
Hoover (1932) lost to FDR, who would go on to win 3 reelection and die in office
Ford (1976) was Nixon's vice-president, serving out the rest of his second term
Carter (1980)
Bush (1992)
Trump (2020)

So 12 or 13 depending on how you count.
Given that 12 is less than 19, we can conclude that Silver is wrong although not massively so.

That is in fact about 61%. English isn't a programming language, so I can't say he's "wrong", but I think there were probably less misleading ways to express that number. Its closer to 2/3rds than it is to half. A 2/3rds chance of winning a 2-person contest is actually kinda massive

If I counted correctly, there were also 4 presidents who never sought re-election (Polk, Pierce, Buchanan and Hayes). Silver's argument seems to be that these should be considered to be dead from the start, and that the split should be 16-19.  For at least Pierce and Buchanan, the argument seems valid.
